Counting the number of cycles of length $k$ in a graph $G(n, p)$
I'm working through a proof in random graph theory and have encountered a step that I don't fully understand. In counting the number of cycles of length $k$ in a graph $G(n, p)$, we proceed by selecting $k$ vertices from $n$ vertices, arranging them in a cycle, and ensuring each vertex is connected to the next.
The total possible number of cycles of length $k$ is:
$$
\binom{n}{k} \frac{(k-1)!}{2}.
$$
I understand that $\binom{n}{k}$ represents the number of ways to choose $k$ vertices from $n$, but I'm confused about where the factor $\frac{(k-1)!}{2}$ comes from.
I understand $(k-1)!$ is the number of circular permutations where rotations are identical, but why is there a division by 2? The standard explanation is that:
Rotations: If we rotate the cycle, it still looks the same (e.g., ABCD is the same as BCDA or DABC).
Reflections: If we reverse the order, it's still the same cycle (e.g., ABCD is the same as DCBA).
But I am having trouble visualizing why this would produce an equivalent graph and is hence excluded from the calculation to avoid overcounting. Could anyone provide any examples to concretely visualize and understand why this is necessary to avoid overcounting?
Thank you for any insights!

The potential cycle ${a,b,c,d}$ is the same as the potential cycle ${a,d,c,b}$.  Starting at vertex $a$ you can go forwards or backwards without changing the cycle.

Here is why we must exclude reflections. Any graph which contains the cycle $ABCD$ will also contain the reversed cycle $DCBA$. Since one cannot exist without the other, it would be silly to count them as separate cycles. Dividing by $2$ ensures that we only count once for $ABCD$.
